# MVC4 Login Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I created a login page within MVC4, now I want to create a cookie to save username and show "Hello + username", also I want a logout button besides the Hello message where basically the user will be redirected to the login page if he clicked on it and the cookie will be deleted. How can I achieve this in MVC4 Asp.Net?

This code is in HomeController.cs:

```
   public ActionResult Login()
        {
           return View();
        }


        //
        // POST: /Home/Login
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

        public ActionResult Login([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] User user)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View();

            var db = new userregistrationEntities2();

            var checkExitUser = (from c in db.Users where c.UserName == user.UserName select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (checkExitUser != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password) && PasswordHashHelper.ValidatePassword(user.Password, checkExitUser.Password))
            {
                if (user.UserName == "Admin")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("AdminIndex");
                }

                Session["userPostcode"] = user.PostCode;
                return RedirectToAction("UserIndex"); // go to index page if the user is valid
            }
            else  
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

                return View();
            }
        }
```

This code is in Views:

```
 </asp:Content> 

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 

    <h2>Log in</h2> 

    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %> 

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%> 

        <fieldset>

            <legend>Fields</legend>



            <p>

                <label for="Nursery_Name">User Name:</label>

                <%= Html.TextBox("UserName") %>

                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("UserName", "*") %>

            </p>



            <p>

                <label for="Email">Password:</label>

                <%= Html.TextBox("Password") %>

                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Password", "*") %>

            </p>



            <p>

                <input type="submit" value="Create" />

            </p>

        </fieldset> 

    <% } %> 

    <div>

        <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>

    </div> 

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Does not MVC 4 out of box come with this feature? Providing a login page and if the user is logged in, it displays the user name? I would not use another cookie to store the user name

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is found in the "Forms" authentication components available in ASP.NET.  Looking at your code example, it looks like you simply need to add the following call after validating the username and password to complete the process of issuing the auth cookie:

```
//creates persistent auth cookie associated with user session
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
```

When you want to log the user out (logout button click), you simply call:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

To display the username in your view, you first want to ensure that the current user is authenticated.  Then you can display the username associated with the current authenticated user through the HttpContext as shown below:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
      <label>Hello @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name</label>
}
```

Please see the following MSDN article that gives a thorough introduction to Forms authentication: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs